# insert data from data that has been posted using checkbox

Tags: php, sql

I have a code that i want to insert the data that has been posted using checkbox. I used table for showing the data.

The black square in the picture is the data that I want to insert

[image]

Comment: seems like you are getting data from the DB and using it to display in the table.. whats the problem you're getting there?

Comment: exactly right..

Comment: And the problem is..?

Comment: I want to use checkbox in the table as insert for different sql table